# How to Call API in WSO2 Business Process Server( BPMN) to get list of Claimable Task

Tags: api, wso2, bpmn, wso2-business-process

In order to integrate the WSO2 BPMN with an external application, I want to make an API call to get all the Package Name or Claimable Task from the WSO2 BPMN. Currently there is no documented ways to make such calls.

When I used the fiddler, to capture the actions from the WSO2 web pages, I see the call made as

https://XX.XX.XX.XX:9443/bpmn-explorer/claimableTask?pagination=1
where the response is entire HTML page but not just the data.

Can some one please explain to me if it's possible to achieve this and where can I find further information regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your own external web application or any other client application, you can use BPMN REST API provided with WSO2 BPS you can get information and do any updates for BPMN processes using it. Please follow [1] for more details.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS350/BPMN+REST+API

Thanks,
Mili